# flashdata not working at all in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys i have tried multiple things like

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata();
$this->session->set_flashdata();
```

but enable to load message with while redirecting i will post my code below have a look and help me out to solve this issue.

**Controller:**

```
        $params = array(
          'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
          'father_name' => $this->input->post('father_name'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
          'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
          'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
          'cnic_no' => $this->input->post('cnic_no'),
          'manager' => $this->input->post('manager'),
          'department_id' => $this->input->post('department_id'),
          'created_by' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
          'position' => $this->input->post('position'),
          'created_at' => $now,
          );
          $this->Maintainer_basic_model->insert($params);
          $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Maintainer added successfully');
          redirect('maintainer_basic/index');
```

**View:**

```
<?php if($message = $this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="alert-success alert">
            <?php echo $message; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: just do
 <?php 
$message = $this->session->flashdata('success')
if($message): ?>

Comment: @DevsiOdedra did'nt worked

Comment: `$message` does not exist as a session variable. Just echo `$this->session->flashdata('success')`. You are setting a key->value pair, where the flashdata key is `success` and the value is `Maintainer added successfulyy`

Comment: @JavierLarroulet i have tried with just $this->session->flashdata('success') but still not working

Answer (score 1):

According to your given code I think you have not load your session library in **config/autoload.php** 
Check the below codes to get idea.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$autoload['packages'] = array();

$autoload['libraries'] = array("session","form_validation","database");

$autoload['drivers'] = array();

$autoload['helper'] = array('url','path','form');

$autoload['config'] = array();

$autoload['language'] = array();

$autoload['model'] = array();
```

After that, you should check function for printing session value in view. Follow the below code to get idea. As **session** library directly makes **session object**. so you can easily check it inside **if()** condition.

```
<?php if($this->session->success): ?>
                <p class="alert alert-success" id="message"><?php echo $this->session->success; ?></p>
           <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->session->error): ?>
                <p class="alert alert-warning" id="message"><?php echo $this->session->error; ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you were absolutely right session was not included in autoload.php i have included it but tried once again but its still not working actually `<?php if($this->session->success): ?>` this condition is not getting true...

Comment: yes during programming you will always try to concentrate 100%